# How to redraw a chart in render function avoiding eternal looping in Highcharts library

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I'm adjusting some values for `dataLabels` in a `render` function, but I need to redraw a chart to apply these changes. Here's my render function:

```js
render: function () {
  const points = this.series[0].points;
          
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

    if (i < points.length - 1) {
      const dataLabel1 = (points[i] as any).dataLabel
      const dataLabel2 = (points[i + 1] as any).dataLabel

      if ((dataLabel1.x + dataLabel1.width) >= dataLabel2.x) {

        dataLabel1.attr({
          y: dataLabel1.y - (dataLabel1.height + 2),
          fill: points[i].color
        });
 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But nothing changes until, for example, the width of a chart is changed. So, I suppose that changes needs the chart to be rendered again to be applied.

I tried to redraw my chart like this:

```js
render: function () {
  const points = this.series[0].points;
          
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

    if (i < points.length - 1) {
      const dataLabel1 = (points[i] as any).dataLabel
      const dataLabel2 = (points[i + 1] as any).dataLabel

      if ((dataLabel1.x + dataLabel1.width) >= dataLabel2.x) {

        dataLabel1.attr({
          y: dataLabel1.y - (dataLabel1.height + 2),
          fill: points[i].color
        });
 
      }
    }
  }

  this.redraw();
}
```

But this leads to the infinite render loop. How can I redraw a chart here or is there any other way to apply the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally redraw the chart, for example:

```
let allowChartRedraw = true;

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        if (allowChartRedraw) {
          allowChartRedraw = false;

          this.redraw();

          allowChartRedraw = true;
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

However, you probably don't need to do that. Using the `attr` method for data labels should be enough, please check this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tyL96pxd/

Comment: Yes, I understand that I shouldn't do that, but after `attr` method position is changed as intended, while fill is not

Comment: Hi @Quribe, You are right, that's because of how data labels are working under the hood. Changes for some individual data labels are not fully supported and should be done for the whole group by: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels The best way would be to create custom labels by using Highcharts.SVGRenderer: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to call this.redraw() in your render function. You can use the update method for data labels to adjust the position and fill color of data labels in a chart and have those changes immediately reflected. Something like this should work,

```js
render: function () {
  const points = this.series[0].points;
          
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {

    if (i < points.length - 1) {
      const dataLabel1 = (points[i] as any).dataLabel
      const dataLabel2 = (points[i + 1] as any).dataLabel

      if ((dataLabel1.x + dataLabel1.width) >= dataLabel2.x) {
        dataLabel1.update({
          y: dataLabel1.y - (dataLabel1.height + 2),
          color: points[i].color // Use 'color' instead of 'fill' to set the text color
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error that says "dataLabel1.update is not a function"